# Port forwarding in 4G modem (huawei) + Router (asus) (pics)

Tags: router, port-forwarding, modem, nat

I have a 4g router (huawei) from my ISP in which I have been able to successfully open the ports when I connect a computer by the ethernet cable. However, it seems impossible once I connect my own router (asus). These are the steps I follow:

1) Disable the firewall

[image]

2) Activate the DMZ towards my own router:

[image]

3) Disable the ISP router DCHP service

[image]

4) Open the ports towards my own router

[image]

5) My own router is configured as wireless router (I also tried as an access point). This is why I get the warning: The WAN IP is not the external IP

[image]

6) I set a static IP

[image]
[image]

7) I activate the DCHP (I get this LAN IP):

[image]
[image]

8) Finally I open the ports toward the computer

[image]

However no luck... No idea what I am doing wrong.

Please could anyone share some advice?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have the same issue (different 4G modem) however I figured out that the issue is from the 4G (data cellular)

turn out that wireless carrier don't handle your internet connection the same as a normal ISP (kind a make sense in away as the primary use is for one device / mobile phone)

So the quick answer is, we can't do port forwarding on data cellular (4G).

UPDATE : after more research, I figured out that with some carrier you can just change the "APN" settings, and then have NAT / Port forwarding / DMZ

Answer (score 0):

Everything is alright. But here, problem is that, you're using modem in front of your router. The modem seems NAT'ed and translating your actual public ip. Please check your ipv4 address on modem itself. This ip will act as your public ip. This ip you've to enter for remote operations. Everything shall work fine. However, you couldn't use DDNS etc.